# Activate Run the libLAS C++ library within R

Tags: c++, macos, r, compilation, lidar-data

I would like to use the libLAS C/C++ library functions within R to import, analyse, export terrestrial lidar data. libLAS is a C/C++ library for reading and writing the very common LAS LiDAR format ( http://liblas.org/index.html ).

Would it be possible to use the Rcpp package to run this library (or other packages)? http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html

Or should I compile and install it in order to use it following the compilation instructions http://liblas.org/compilation.html ? I am working on a MacOSx 10.6.5. As such I could also use it within Open Source GIS GRASS as described in the following wiki http://grass.osgeo.org/wiki/LIDAR#Micro-tutorial_for_LAS_data_import .

All advice is welcome related to reading and processing LIDAR data with R/GRASS.
Thanks,
Jan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the question

> Would it be possible to use the Rcpp
>   package to run this library (or other
>   packages)?

the answer is whopping *Yup!* as using it for glueing [R](http://www.r-project.org) to a given C/C++ library was pretty much the reason [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) was written for.  Come and see the documentation and/or the [rcpp-devel](http://news.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.rcpp) list for examples.  There is some exciting new stuff happening with *Rcpp modules* but you can also get going the old-fashioned way of writing your wrapper.  [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) makes mapping and R and C++ types (in both directions) a lot easier.

Comment: What a lay-up.  No +1 from me.  You didn't even have to try. ;-)

Comment: Hm, I still have the feeling that the answer was a) appropriate and b) correct so that I not sure that a score of zero does it justice.

Comment: OK OK, that's 30K +10 for you then ;-)

Comment: Thanks :)  I wanted to applaud your for that SSD read/write performance question.  Nice focus, and of course empirics. Great job.